# Is there a way to do a incremental export from mssql to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I exported a SQL database to *MySQL* database through *Laravel seeder*. The full export requires 6-7 hours. Now, after the full export, is there a way to export only new or updated records? Not all of the database tables have a `timestamp` column.

Thanks

Comment: please check with below solution you can extract the latest records which is insert in SQL DB table.

Answer (score 0):

If in your `SQL` table if any **date column** is available then you can extract it ,because when you are updating or inserting any records then date column will be updated with current date and time.

So query will be ...

```
Use [Your_Database]
GO
SELECT *
FROM Your_table
WHERE your_date_column >= DATEADD(HH, - DATEPART(HH, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```